# Laravel 5: Trying to get property of non-object error with relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Im running the latest version of Laravel.
I am trying to set up relationships with tables but I seem to always get some sort of error. The data that I want to be displayed is displayed but then under everything there is a big error saying:

ErrorException in routes.php line 26:
Trying to get property of non-object

In my routes.php file this is the code:

```
 Route::get('select', function() {
 $users = App\UserInfo::all();

   foreach ($users as $u) {
       echo $u->userID.' USERNAME: '.$u->userData->username.'<br/>';
       echo $u->userOption->dis_joindate.'<br/>'; // Line 26
  }
 });
```

Line 25 seems to work fine printing no errors, though the next line gives the object error.

This is my UserInfo Model php file:

[image: UserInfo.php model]

And this is my Options Model php file:

[image: Options.php model]

All that my database supplies (in the useroptions table) is and id, userID, dis_joindate, dis_location, dis_posts and dis_likes. And the last 4 colums just give text.

This is the image of the output on the page when all this is ran:

[image]

Comment: check for user "Lad". I believe that `useroptions` table don't have data for user "Lad"

Comment: `useroptions` does have an entry with userID = 27 (the first part of the display is their id) but the `useroptions` does have data for the user.

Comment: can you please post full trace that you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here (assuming relationship are defined well) might be data. You might not have related data for each object.

So instead of:

```
foreach ($users as $u) {
   echo $u->userID.' USERNAME: '.$u->userData->username.'<br/>';
   echo $u->userOption->dis_joindate.'<br/>'; // Line 26
}
```

you should rather use:

```
foreach ($users as $u) {
   echo $u->userID.' USERNAME: '.(($u->userData) ? $u->userData->username : '-').'<br/>';
   echo (($u->userOption) ? $u->userOption->dis_joindate : '-').'<br/>'; // Line 26
}
```

In addition to lower number of queries instead of:

```
$users = App\UserInfo::all();
```

you should use eager loading like so:

```
$users = App\UserInfo::with('userData', 'userOption')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `userOption` relationship isn't setup quite right. Because of this, the relationship will (unexpectedly to you) return `null` when the related record isn't found, and you'll get this error when you attempt to access `dis_joindate` on the `null` object.

In the comments you mention that you do have a `useroptions` record with a `userID` of 27, however that is not the record that is being loaded. The way your relationship is setup, it is actually looking for a `useroptions` record with an `id` of 27 (not `userID`).

When defining a `belongsTo` relationship, the second parameter is the name of the foreign key field on the Model which has the `belongsTo` relationship. In this case, when you specify `userID`, you're specifying `userinfo.userID`. The third parameter is the name of the field on the related Model on which to join. If not specified, it defaults to the primary key (usually `id`). Since you have not specified this parameter, it will default to `useroptions.id`.

If you would like relate records where `userinfo.userID = useroptions.userID`, you need to add the name of the related field to your relationship:

```
public function userOption() {
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Options', 'userID', 'userID');
}
```

You didn't mention the structure of the userData table, but you may want to check that out, as well.

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with relaitions in userOptions, it should have at least one record for every user.
in this case user 27 have no recorde in table userOptions and it its value is null and you try to use a property of null object